# How can I get the InteractiveMesh library to work with my JavaFX Mavn project?

Tags: java, maven, javafx-3d

Im trying to use this importer http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html to import an STL file as a triangle mesh, i get no errors in the IDE when i write this code:

```java
        StlMeshImporter stlImporter = new StlMeshImporter();
        stlImporter.read(this.getClass().getResource("Tachi_LP.stl"));
```

using this import statement

```java
import com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.stl.StlMeshImporter;
```

which also doesnt give me an error in the IDE.

I downloaded the zip folder, unzipped it and added it as a library under the project structure in intelliJ, i did the same with the javaFX library im using (versiion 17 directly from their site)
[image]

lib is the javafx library and the highlighted one is the importer Library. When i try to run the program i get this error:
`package com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.stl does not exist` Do i have the wrong version or is this no longer compatible with the newer versions of JavaFX?

Answer (score 1):

As long as i know the interactive mesh works only java vesion 8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).